# Math Quiz Counter

Tags: javascript, html

Recently I have been making a math quiz for fun. However, I have tried to come up with a counter to count up the user's correct answers, and display the count at the bottom of the page. I have tried looking up this before but have found nothing.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div>
  <p>What is 18 + 4?</p>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="lol">
    <button id="q1" onclick="lmao()">Answer</button>
  </div>
  <p id="q1c" class="correct"></p>
  <p id="q1i" class="incorrect"></p>

  <p>What is 19 + 21?</p>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="loll">
    <button id="q2" onclick="lmfao()">Answer</button>
  </div>
  <p id="q2c" class="correct"></p>
  <p id="q2i" class="incorrect"></p>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function lmao() {
  if (document.getElementById("lol").value == "22") {
    document.getElementById("q1c").innerHTML = "Correct!";
    alert('Correct');
  } else {
    document.getElementById("q1i").innerHTML = "Incorrect!";
    alert('Incorrect');
  }
}

function lmfao() {
  if (document.getElementById("loll").value == "40") {
    document.getElementById("q2c").innerHTML = "Correct!";
    alert('Correct');
  } else {
    document.getElementById("q2i").innerHTML = "Incorrect!";
    alert('Incorrect');
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide information on _how_ the code is producing a result that deviates from expected behavior. ie provide any errors, or simply describe the output.

Comment: I updated answer with your code, hopefully that helps a little better with understanding.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using separate `<p>` tags for marking if the answers are incorrect or correct, you can simplify it down to one `<p>` tag with different id's, and just update the text inside them, and then we use the simple JavaScript notation to update the color of the font: `object.style.color = "green"`. This provides much cleaner HTML.

Here is a working example (I stripped out all the excess tags and styles):

```js
var answer1Count = 0;
var answer2Count = 0;
var correctCount = 0;

function answer1() {
  var answer = document.getElementById("problem1");
  var alert = document.getElementById("problem1Alert");
  
  if (answer.value == "22") {
    alert.textContent = "Correct!";
    alert.style.color = "green";
    correctCount +=1; //update global count of correct answers
    answer1Count +=1;
    document.getElementById("correctCount").textContent = correctCount;
  } else {
    if (answer1Count !== 0) {
      answer1Count -=1;
      correctCount -=1;
      document.getElementById("correctCount").textContent = correctCount;
     }
    alert.textContent = "Incorrect!";
    alert.style.color = "Red";
  }
}

function answer2() {
  var answer = document.getElementById("problem2");
  var alert = document.getElementById("problem2Alert");
  
  if (answer.value == "40") {
    alert.textContent = "Correct!";
    alert.style.color = "green";
    answer2Count +=1; //update global count of correct answers
    correctCount +=1;
    document.getElementById("correctCount").textContent = correctCount;
  } else {
    if (answer2Count !== 0) {
      answer2Count -=1;
      correctCount -= 1;
      document.getElementById("correctCount").textContent = correctCount;
    }
    alert.textContent = "Incorrect!";
    alert.style.color = "Red";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>What is 18 + 4?</p>
<input type="text" id="problem1">
<button onclick="answer1()">Answer</button>

<p id="problem1Alert"></p>

<p>What is 19 + 21?</p>
<input type="text" id="problem2">
<button onclick="answer2()">Answer</button>

<p id="problem2Alert"></p>

<p>Correct Answer Count: <b id="correctCount">0</b></p>
```

Instead of using `innerHTML`, we use `textContent` it is safer and faster for updating with pure text because it does not have to parse for HTML. You can easily search around SO for the disadvantages of using `innerHTML`.

In addition, I would avoid inline styling with CSS at all costs. It makes your code much harder to read. I recommend putting all your styles in a separate stylesheet and just including that style sheet inside your `<head>` tag like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Comment: The reasons i used seperate tags is so that incorrect would be red and correct would be green

Comment: We can do that as well with just a single alert tag. I'll update! :)

Comment: @Carter check now